# meaning of parenthesis in nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx

i just started with nginx and there is this rewrite line which I am not clear about:

```
server {
    server_name server.com;

    location /rt/v1 {
       rewrite ^/rt/v1/(.*) /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://192.168.8.8:15555;
    }
}
```

Let's say we key in http://server.com/rt/v1/index.html, is the result http://192.168.8.8:15555/index.html? What does the .* inside the () for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a regex capturing group.

When you look at this command:

```
rewrite ^/rt/v1/(.*) /$1 break;
```

It means that URLs with the pattern `/rt/v1/whatever` will be rewritten to `/whatever`:

- The `(.*)` captures any sequence of characters following `/rt/v1/`
- The `$1` references the first captured group